# Searching through Sheetnode data in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules, spreadsheet

I'm using Sheetnode  -- http://drupal.org/project/sheetnode -- to upload a big spreadsheet full of property data for a real estate tool I'm working on.

I've successfully uploaded all my spreadsheets; what I'm stuck on is creating the view (I'm very unfamiliar with the Views module).

Is there any way I can use Views to search through a particular column of Sheetnode data, i.e., how do I query a particular column and return results meeting a particular condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sheetnode integrates with core Search, so cell content is indexed as part of node indexing. If you use the "Search: Search Terms" exposed filter, you will be able to search trough spreadsheet content. But you can't specify to only search through a particular column.

Comment: Huh... I'll probably have to rethink how to proceed, then. Creating this data as CCK-enabled nodes might be the better option... Hey, if you're the same infojunkie as the developer, know if extended Views support is planned for the future? :) Thanks for the response!

Comment: Yes I am the same infojunkie. If you have feature requests, please file them in the Sheetnode issue queue!

Answer (score 0):

Add the fields you want to query as filters, you can then expose these fields creating a search form for your view.

Comment: Is there another way to do this? You can't expose Sheetnode columns as fields AFAIK.